# filling innerhtml of dropdown menu with specific data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a xmlhttp/php problem. I have one drop-down menu where people are able to select municipality. Then I want to return a list of possible options within that municipality to a secondary drop-down menu.

people first select a municipality (html code below):

```
<select name="pszplaats" id="gemeente" onchange="fdisplay();loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectgem)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Gemeente']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Gemeente'];?>
    </option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

loadXMLDoc is the function that should send this answer to the (php-)server and retreive a list of names matching those in that municipality. 
so far my relevant java/xml/ajax code is this:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xmlhttp;
      gem=document.getElementById("gemeente").value;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
      else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                 {
                 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                 }
           }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/dynamic.php",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send();
      alert(gem)

           }
```

Alert(gem) shows the selected option, so I know that at least this works.
the php to retreive the right values is this:

```
$gem=$_POST["pszplaats"];
$gennam=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM psz WHERE Gemeente=$gem");
echo $gennam["$gem"];
```

now the problem lies in the filling of the secondary drow-down menu

```
<select name="psznaam" id="test" style="display:none">
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectall)){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['NaamPSZ']; ?>"><?php echo $row['NaamPSZ'];?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

after the java function is finished the drop-down menu is completely empty. Can anybody tel me how I can actually get the relevant data in that menu?
any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you define $selectall var ?

Comment: yes, sorry. $selectall = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM psz");

Comment: Are you sure there is some data in this table ? Also note that your select has a style="display:none" so it won't appear :)

Comment: yes, the box is hidden until the first drop-down is selected. The it appears (shortly with $selectall as contents), and then when the values should be returned it goes blank again.

Comment: have you tried appendChild instead of innerHTML?

Comment: with appendChild, the 2nd drop-down menu is filled with all of the options, not just the ones for the selection municipality, but thanks for the suggestion. At least something different is happening ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have not sent `gem` with the url. try `xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/dynamic.php?gem="+gem,true);` 
and in your `dynamic.php` page pick it up by `$_POST["gem"]`

Comment: thanks, that's already one step of which I wasn't sure if it actually worked. Is there an easy way for me to check whether the correct info from the database is actually sent back? Because I still don't see anything change in the web page.

Comment: @Jeroen you are basic ajax. so you need to maintain the rules of ajax. The above is the rule for ajax.

Comment: okay, but how would I check if this code actually sent something to my php? If in my php I would create $test=$_POST["gem"], and I'd want to retrieve $test in my html. I can't simply writ <?php echo $test?>, because it's not reloading the entire page, right? So how would I go about this then?